# How to draw Google map neighborhood boundaries?

Tags: api, dictionary

I want to draw Google defined neighborhood boundaries over JavaScript V3 Map Api. I have found it but couldn't get a better solution for this. If you explorer Google map and search for any location Google highlights the boundary in "Red" color. So I want the same but to draw a poly lines.

Comment: Sounds to me like you want a polygon? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Polygon

Answer (score 1):

The closest I can think of is using google geocoding and get a bounding box from it. For example, if you query http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=southwark , the google geocode gives the following,

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Southwark",
               "short_name" : "Southwark",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Greater London",
               "short_name" : "Gt Lon",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United Kingdom",
               "short_name" : "GB",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "SE1",
               "short_name" : "SE1",
               "types" : [ "postal_code_prefix", "postal_code" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "London",
               "short_name" : "London",
               "types" : [ "postal_town" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Southwark, London, Greater London SE1, UK",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 51.502781,
               "lng" : -0.087738
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 51.50972609999999,
                  "lng" : -0.07173059999999999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 51.4958349,
                  "lng" : -0.1037454
               }
            }
         },
         "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Here you can use the "geometry" object to get a bounding box for the result.